# WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole takes into account groups inside groups?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iprincipal

If I have an principal that pertains to a group that pertains to a group that pertains to a group that is added to the built it role "Administrator" will a call to `principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)` return true?

Comment: Did you consider just testing it?

Comment: What it does and what it should do are different things. I would like to avoid testing the method on every platform to find it's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on info supplied it will return true yes. However, as Blam says just one test should be sufficient to ascertain what the behaviour is